# jQuery click through on table row excluding certain cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a massive table and i want to be able to click on the  and go to another page. However I dont want to allow the click through on the first  and the last . So its everything in between really.

```
 $(".dataTable td").click(function(){
     window.location.href = "LINK";
});
```

Cheers

Comment: is this going to be on browsers that support CSS3 or a general solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$('.dataTable td:not(:first-child, :last-child)').click(function(){
     window.location.href = "LINK";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dataTable td").not(':first-child, :last-child').on('click',  function(){
     window.location.href = "LINK";
});
```